# How to find the deepest UNIQUE node of a binary tree in C

Tags: c, algorithm, search, data-structures, tree

I am reading commands from a text file. A sample input is:

```
Create Key 2
Create Key 1
Create Key 3
Update Key 1
Delete Key 2
```

I want to reduce operations my program executes. For example, it is useless to create Key2, only to delete it after.

In order to minimize the number of operations I decided to store these in a binary search tree. In the book "Introduction to algorithms", third edition, by Cormen, Leiserson, Rivest and Stein, a binary search tree (BST) is explicitly defined as allowing duplicates. The letter after the key stands for either Create, Update or Delete. A simple example would be as follows:

```
       K2(C)
      /    \
     /      \
  K1(C)     K3(C)      <-- The deepest Key3 appears here.
     \       /   
    K1(U)   K2(D)      <-- The deepest Key1 and Key2 appear here.
```

As pointed out I would like to be able to extract all the unique keys in their deepest position, to minimize the number of operations. I could not find any reference to this in CLRS, maybe I was looking for the wrong thing..

A simple search, which returns a key does not suffice, since it returns the first node found, therefore breadth-first or depth-first search would not work.

```
struct node* search(struct node* root, int key) 
{ 
    // Base Cases: root is null or key is present at root 
    if (root == NULL || root->key == key) 
       return root; 

    // Key is greater than root's key 
    if (root->key < key) 
       return search(root->right, key); 

    // Key is smaller than root's key 
    return search(root->left, key);
```

[How to handle duplicates in Binary Search Tree?](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-handle-duplicates-in-binary-search-tree/) describes how to handle inserting duplicates not how to handle extracting duplicates which appear last.

Another idea would be to return the right most  unique key as follows:

```
struct node * maxValueNode(struct node* node) 
{ 
    struct node* current = node; 

    /* loop down to find the rightmost leaf */
    while (current->right != NULL) 
        current = current->right; 

    return current; 
}
```

Am I missing something here? How can I how to find the deepest UNIQUE node of a binary tree?

Comment: make a map of key, <depth, leafnodepointer>. When you add something to the tree, check if its in the map. Update if its depth in three is greater than map value. Still, don´t think you need binary trees for this problem, would help explaining more in detail your rules on deleting useless operations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't get why you would need a BST for that but anyway, you could make a search that does not stop at first occurrence and keeps track of the deepest node found using pointers. This should do the trick :

```
void deepest_search(struct node * root, int key, int currentDepth, int * maxDepth, struct node * deepestNode)
{
  // Do nothing if root is null
  if (root != NULL)
  {
        // Update deepest node if needed
        if(root->key == key && currentDepth > *maxDepth)
        {
            *maxDepth = currentDepth;
            *deepestNode = *root;
        }

        // Might need to search both sides because of duplicates
        // Can make this an if/else if duplicates are always in left/right subtree
        if(root->key <= key)
            deepest_search(root->right, key, currentDepth + 1, maxDepth, deepestNode);
        if(root->key >= key)
            deepest_search(root->left, key, currentDepth + 1, maxDepth, deepestNode);
    }
}
```

I tested it on your (small) example and it seems to work fine:

```
struct node
{
    int key;
    int val;
    struct node *left, *right;
};

void main(void)
{
    int key = 1;
    int currentDepth = 1;

    struct node n5 = {2, 5, NULL, NULL};
    struct node n4 = {1, 4, NULL, NULL};
    struct node n3 = {3, 3, &n5, NULL};
    struct node n2 = {1, 2, NULL, &n4};
    struct node n1 = {2, 1, &n2, &n3};

    struct node * deepestNode = (struct node *) malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    int maxDepth = 0;

    deepest_search(&n1, key, currentDepth, &maxDepth, deepestNode);
    printf("%d\n", maxDepth);
    printf("%d\n", deepestNode->val);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure about handling duplicate values then the article you mentioned gives a great idea how to handle them in BSTs. Assuming you implement one of those two inserting methods let's see how you can implement deleting a node in any of them.

## 1. Pushing duplicates to the right or left subtree (ugly solution)

If you chose this solution then if you find a node with given value ( let's call the value X) there is no guarantee that it does not appear somewhere else down the tree. You must search for the value in one of the subtrees. There is more to it, you have to propagate a depth of every node with value X and choose the deepest one. That requires some coding. That's why I think that the second solution is far better.

## 2. Counting values (better)

According to this method, every node holds a counter that tells how many times given value has occured. If you want to delete one instance of this value, then if counter is >1 then you just decrement the counter. Otherwise if counter == 1 you delete the node as you would do in a regular BST.